# 'Open Issues' in Sonar Qube should exclude "INFO" Violations

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

Currently there is a RULE on the Quality Gate such that "Open Issues" should not be more than 50. But I want to exclude "INFO" Violations to be part of "Open Issues" for all projects of the quality Gate i.e. INFO issues should not be considered but all other issues like Blocker, Critical, Major and Minor should be considered when calculating "Open Issues". How can I achieve this. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box way to set a criteria on the sum of an all-but set of issues. As a workaround, you might consider a quota for each severity:

- 0 Blockers
- 0 Criticals
- 20 Majors
- 30 Minors

I know this doesn't achieve exactly what you're after, but to get that, you'd have to write a plugin and calculate a new metric: NON_INFO_ISSUES (or something like that).